# Local notification if arrays date is same as today date

Tags: ios, notifications

I have one array something like that:

```
_combinedBirthdates(
"03/05/2013",
"09/22/1986",
"03/02/1990",
"03/02",
"08/22/1989",
"11/02/1990",
"07/08",
"08/31/1990",
"05/13",
"07/11/2007",
"10/07/2010",
"02/20/1987")
```

i want Local notification if today date is same as date in above array

I used following logic for notification:

```
NSLog(@" _combinedBirthdates%@",_combinedBirthdates);  
NSDateFormatter *Formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDate *date1 =[NSDate date];
NSString *string =[Formatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
NSDate *todaydate =[Formatter1 dateFromString:string];

for (int i=0;i<_combinedBirthdates.count;i++)
{
    NSDate *date =[Formatter1 dateFromString:[_combinedBirthdates objectAtIndex:i ]];
    if(date == todaydate){
    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.alertBody = @"birthdate notification";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
```

Now my questions:

1. Is this code ok?
2. Do I need device to test this code or I can test it in simulator?
3. When notification will appear? at 12:00 am?
4. Will notification appear if application is closed?
5. If code is not ok then please modify it.

Comment: Have you tried running it in simulator?

Comment: i dont understand how to check this thing ? when notification will appear?

Comment: You've changed the accepted answer on two questions in quick succession, in each case to a rather weaker one. This certainly *looks* suspicious...

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code had some mistakes, I had rectified here.
2. Yes, we can able to run this in simulator for testing.
3. UILocalNotifications will fire on the date which we specified on the respective notification.  While assigning the notification, what is the time mentioned that will we taken into consideration. If we not set the time then the device time will the considered for the date which is mentioned for firing.
4. Even the applications is closed also, the local notification will fire, but until we tap on the action button it won't. see this specification...

See the modified code....

```
NSMutableArray *newBirthDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];;
for(int i = 0; i < [_combinedBirthdates count]; i++)
{
    NSString *date = [_combinedBirthdates objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *dateComponents = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    if([dateComponents count] == 3)
    {
        [newBirthDates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[dateComponents objectAtIndex:0], [dateComponents objectAtIndex:1]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [newBirthDates addObject:date];
    }
}
NSDateFormatter *Formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSDate *date1 =[NSDate date];
NSString *string =[Formatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
NSDate *todaydate =[Formatter1 dateFromString:string];

for (int i=0;i<newBirthDates.count;i++)
{
    NSDate *date =[Formatter1 dateFromString:[newBirthDates objectAtIndex:i ]];
    NSComparisonResult result = [date compare:todaydate];
    if(result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate = date;
        localNotif.alertBody = @"birthdate notification";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
}
```

Comment: When notification will appear? at 12:00 am?
Will notification appear if application is closed?

Comment: @user1660882: Why did you accept the much poorer answer instead of this one?